# How to pull data from clipboard into static file

Tags: excel, vba, static, paste

I'd like to know if it is possible to paste (or pull) data from a clipboard into either a static file (such as a created PDF) or a protected environment (such as a protected Excel sheet) where there is no ability for a user to enter/modify any text aside from pasting it.

Data will be coming in through a serial port, and pasted through the successor to SerialKeys.  I cannot find any information about Excel VBA commands for blocking key-ins/deletions other than pasting as values only.  I can accommodate a wide variety of file types as output, but the main thing that I need is to restrict any modifications/deletions.

Comment: Have you tried anything that you can share? the short answer is yes, you can pull data from the clipboard and you can protect a sheet and its contents via VBA